# Creating RSA Private Key from PFX (PKCS #12) file

Tags: encryption, certificate, ssl-certificate, rsa, pem

I'm trying to get a private RSA key from a pkcs #12 file.

I've tried running the standard

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out priv.pem -in domain.com.pfx
```

However this results in a key file like the one below:

```
Bag Attributes
Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
friendlyName: xxxxxxxx
Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
X509v3 Key Usage: 10
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The server that I need to put it into canot handle the key file, and when I look at the examples data I see a file like below

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,2CF27DD60B8BB3FF
```

And of cause the key is present in both files.
However it seems the server will only accept RSA Private key file, and it seems to me like the output I get is a X509v3 file, any one know how to get this to an RSA Private key file?

Comment: try adding *-nodes* after *-nocerts* to create an unencrypted private key

Comment: Thanks. Tried this as well, but i cannot remove the password from the output pemfile and this still leaves me with the X509v3 file

Comment: @Dorana I wanted to create a certificate like yours, my pem file does not contain the first code section which has Microsoft library reference and x509v3, etc. What tool did you use?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well - using a text editor to remove the offending lines may be easiest. Otherwise below will clean up the bag attributes:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in x.pfx  -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:123456 | openssl rsa -out privkey.pem
```

and can also be used to get der/net

```
openssl pkcs12 -in x-fred.p12  -nocerts -nodes -passin pass: | openssl rsa -outform DER -out privkey.der
```

which may be in fact the format you want. It is fairly common for tools to not accept a password less private key though (and a lot of tools will silently fail if the # of chars are not at least 4 or 6). So in those cases change the tailend to:

```
.... | openssl rsa -passout pass:123456 -out privkey.pem
.... | openssl rsa -passout pass:123456 -out privkey.der -outform der
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows 7 64bit, you can simply use your command.But in mac and linux, you should do the following steps:

1, create your pem file:
openssl pkcs12 -in xxx.pfx -out xxx.pem

2, create your rsa private key :
openssl pkcs12 -in xxx.pfx -passin pass:yourpassword | openssl rsa -des3 -passout pass:yourpassowrd -out xxx.key

this step will create the key file with the conten:"
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,2CF27DD60B8BB3FF"

3, open your .pem and .key file in a text editor, and replace the origin key"
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----" in the .pem file
with the rsa key in the .key file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "$1" \
    -nocerts -nomacver \
    -passin file:<(cat "$pw") \
    -passout file:<(cat "$pw") |
sed -n '/^-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----/,/^-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----/p'
```